# Detected a connection attempt to an ASP.NET SignalR Server. This client only supports connecting to an ASP.NET Core SignalR Server in react

Tags: reactjs, signalr

I am using react to connect a signalR server which is a third party by '@microsoft/signalr' package. But each time getting error

> Detected a connection attempt to an ASP.NET SignalR Server. This
> client only supports connecting to an ASP.NET Core SignalR Server

My code for connection is:

```
    import * as SignalR from '@microsoft/signalr';

    const connectionUrl = "https://signals.fanbotuk.com/signalr/hubs";

    let connection = new SignalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl(connectionUrl).withHubProtocol(new SignalR.JsonHubProtocol()).withAutomaticReconnect().build();

    async function start() {
      connection.start().then(
                           console.log('hub connected')
                         ).catch(err =>{
                            console.log('connection error');
                            console.error(err)
                         });
    };
    start();    

    export default connection;
```

getting console hub connected but after that getting above error.